# Removing setInterval

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, setinterval, youtube-javascript-api

How would I remove setInterval from this code and for it to still work properly. I was told it's not needed in the code, but I can't figure out how to remove it and for the code to work **the same as it did before.**

And it's important that it works the same as it did when setInterval was in the code.

What I mean by, '**still work properly**' is, The video should appear on **1 Click**, and '**not**' 2 Clicks.

Also, with the setInterval Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/63/

None of the YouTube stuff is cached in the browser until it is clicked.

**It would need to work the same way as that too.**

This is something I cannot figure out how to do.

**setInterval Code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/63/

```
let apiIsReady = false;
    let timer;
    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        apiIsReady = true;
    };
    function init(opts) {
        loadPlayer();
        timer = setInterval(function checkAPIReady() {
            if (apiIsReady) {
                timer = clearInterval(timer);
                addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    return {
        init
    };
}());
```

**This is the whole code:**

```
const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
    "use strict";
    const players = [];

    function loadPlayer() {
        const tag = document.createElement("script");
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
        const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        player.setVolume(50); // percent
    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        const player = event.target;
        if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
            const otherVideos = (video) => video !== player;
            const pauseVideo = (video) => video.pauseVideo();
            players.filter(otherVideos).forEach(pauseVideo);
        }
        const playerVars = player.b.b.playerVars;
        if (playerVars.loop && event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            player.seekTo(playerVars.start);
        }
    }

    function addVideo(video, desiredPlayerVars) {
        const videoId = video.getAttribute("data-id");
        const defaultPlayerVars = {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 1,
            showinfo: 1,
            rel: 0,
            iv_load_policy: 3,
            cc_load_policy: 0,
            fs: 0,
            disablekb: 1
        };
        const playerVars = Object.assign(defaultPlayerVars, desiredPlayerVars);
        players.push(new YT.Player(video, {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            videoId: videoId,
            // defaultPlayerVars,
            playerVars,
            events: {
                "onReady": onPlayerReady,
                "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
            }
        }));
    }
    let apiIsReady = false;
    let timer;
    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
        apiIsReady = true;
    };
    function init(opts) {
        loadPlayer();
        timer = setInterval(function checkAPIReady() {
            if (apiIsReady) {
                timer = clearInterval(timer);
                addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
            }
        }, 100);
    }
    return {
        init
    };
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 900,
                end: 1200
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playa");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playb");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playc");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playd");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playe");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playf");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playg");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playh");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
(function iife() {
    "use strict";
    const show = (el) => el.classList.remove("hide");

    function coverClickHandler(evt) {
        const wrapper = evt.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        show(wrapper);
        videoPlayer.init({
            video: wrapper.querySelector(".video"),
            playerVars: {
                start: 30,
                end: 50
            }
        });
    }
    const cover = document.querySelector(".playi");
    cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());
```

Comment: what do you mean by `still work properly.`?

Comment: The video should appear on 1 Click, and not 2 Clicks.

Comment: Are you sure you were told about removing it? because I think you should replace it with `setTimeout`

Comment: I'm still looking to remove it because I was told it's not needed in the code. Maybe someone else on here might know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by calling your loader inside your constructor.

```
loadPlayer();
function init(opts) {
  addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/1/)

**Edit:**

You can check and see if your api is ready then do your stuff other wise call you loader function and also append your `opts` argument to an array. then when your `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` fired then call your `init` function using your array of arguments:

**Your Init Function**

```
function init(opts) {
    loadPlayer();
    if (apiIsReady) {
      addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
    }
    else
    {
      waitting_inits.push(opts)
    }
}
```

**Your CallBack Function**

```
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
  apiIsReady = true;
  load_all_waitting_inits()
};


var waitting_inits=[];
function load_all_waitting_inits()
{
    for(var opts of waitting_inits)
  {
    init(opts);
  }
}
```

and [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/30/) is working jsfiddle.

***NEW EDIT:***

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/h93qzu0t/1/) is a jsffiddel without browser freeze problem.

Comment: Not working still because all the YouTune stuff is showing up in Network (Inspect Element Browser) before anything is clicked. Bad Code. All that YouTube stuff should not be showing at all.

Comment: With the setInterval Code: https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/63/ None of the YouTube stuff is cached in the browser until it is clicked.

Comment: @JDawg Is it possible to use `setTimeout` or not. Not using it as a recursive function, just to delay calling a function.

Comment: You can provide an example if you want.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. Maybe someone can take a look at what you did and maybe improve it better. Thank you again.

Comment: If I remove this line from the code, the browser freezes.
apiIsReady = true; / How would that be fixed? / Remove this line from the code.
apiIsReady = true; / Then try clicking on the image. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/30/

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: I don't see any change in your fiddle and also I don't understand what you mean. but if you remove `apiIsReady = true;` then because of the `if` inside the `init` function, none of your videos will be played.

Comment: Do these precise steps:

Delete this line:  "apiIsReady = true;" / Press Run / Then try clicking on a Play Button. / Now do you see what I mean? "None of your videos will be played, and the browser will freeze."

Comment: So why are you going to delete that line. it is necessary for code to work correctly.

Comment: Why does it cause the browser to freeze though? What's the reason?

Comment: With that line removed, if I click on any of the play buttons the browser freezes. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/49/ How come?

Comment: I was just told this: If you remove apiIsReady = true; then it creates an infinity loop. And that's why, the browser will freeze.

Comment: I was told this: "You could check if array contains that value, if not, then push it." How would I do that?

Comment: if you want to prevent infinite loop, you can just check `apiIsReady` inside your `load_all_waitting_inits` function and if it was `true` then do your loop other wise do nothing.

Comment: You mean like this? Check if array includes object. https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/54/ / function init(opts) {
    loadPlayer();
    if (apiIsReady) {
      addVideo(opts.video, opts.playerVars || {});
    }
    else if(!waitting_inits.includes(opts)) // if array doesn't include opts then push
    {
      waitting_inits.push(opts)
    }
}

Comment: No. see my new jsfiddle in the answer.

Comment: Can you explain for me what's the difference between Your Way: https://jsfiddle.net/h93qzu0t/1/ / And how this does it? https://jsfiddle.net/5umd9zfg/54/ What's the difference and better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var opts={video:null,playerVars:null}
function init(options){
    opts=options
}
window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
    addVideo(opts.video||{}, opts.playerVars||{});
}
```

I hope that this will helps!